# Ionic can't emulate or run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, emulation

I try to generate a application, but i've some probleme and i don't know what to do..
I try to emulate/run on android but i've this error message:

> FAILURE BUILD failed with an exception
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'
>
> failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle
>
> "Connection to https://repo1.maven.org" refused

If someone have a idea for fixe the problem, help me! :(

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: builder can't access a host.
To resolve try the following.

- Verify your internet connection
- Make sure you are not behind proxy if you do please read [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3Aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)
- Try run `ping repo1.maven.org` or `host repo1.maven.org`

Comment: I'm behind a proxy, i try to configure the proxy but i think is not good... ^^"

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. If you still stuck please paste `gradle.properties` and `build.gradle` and mentioned commands output relevant fragments.